# Как вставить php скрипт в html скрипт?

Tags: php, html5

Есть часть плеера html5 в который нужно вставить сслыку на php рандомайзер видио.

Скрипт html5:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist version="1" xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/">
     <trackList>
         <track>
             <title>1-серия</title>
             <location>СЮДА НУЖНО ВСТАВИТЬ СКРИПТ PHP</location>
             <image>/img/anisoul.png</image>
         </track>         
     </trackList>
</playlist>
```

В общем сюда нужно вставить ссылку на php файл с необходимым мне контентом как это сделать?

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что php исполняется на стороне сервера и генерирует страницу, а html5 работает на стороне клиента, в браузере ...

Comment: @Mike более того это не `html` а `xml`)

Comment: Может все таки надо вставить ссылку на видео, а не скрипт?

Comment: Более того, ни `html` ни `php` это не скрипт

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете отдать xml через php, а внутри уже вставить переменную, например так

```
header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");

$text = 'hello world';

$response = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist version="1" xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/">
     <trackList>
         <track>
             <title>1-серия</title>
             <location>' . $text . '</location>
             <image>/img/anisoul.png</image>
         </track>         
     </trackList>
</playlist>';

echo $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого необходимо, чтобы расширение файла было php и тогда можно делать так

```
<location>
     <?php require_once("../add_functions.html")?>
</location>
```